# R / lm: Named variables instead of formulas?

Tags: r, lm

Is it possible to hand over the elements of a very basic linear model to the `lm()` function as variables instead of a formula? I.e. instead of

```
lin_mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```

something like this:

```
lin_mod <- lm(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, data = iris)
```

Background: I know I can hand over variables to formulas via `paste()`, but this gets tricky when working with multiple variable handovers inside functions. In the end, I would like to be able to use curly bracket variable handover in `lm()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reformulate` and passs that inside `lm`

```
lm(reformulate('Sepal.Width', response = 'Sepal.Length'), data = iris)
#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate("Sepal.Width", response = "Sepal.Length"), 
    data = iris)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#     6.5262      -0.2234
```